# powershell regex and e.164

Tags: regex, powershell

In powershell, I'm trying to create a E.164 type regex for a number of countries. I explicitly need to have the (+) plus in my number and in most cases multi number country codes. 
For some reason: '+421233339135' does not match `'/^(\+[4][2][1])?([1-9]\d\d{7})$'`

+421 is the country code, the first digit after the CC needs to be between 1-9, the rest can be any number then 9 digits afterwards is the DID number.

hope someone can help:-)

Comment: What do you mean it does not? It does. https://regex101.com/r/hH5oW1/1. Share the code you have.

Comment: when I remove / from the beginning of the regex in powershell, -match is true. I'm also finding another issue that may solve my problem -- '+421233339135' is converted to 4.21233E+11 in Excel. When I open the same CSV file in notepad, the right format is there.

Comment: @user3220278 That last issue is an *Excel formatting issue*, has nothing to do with PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason: '+421233339135' does not match `'/^(\+[4][2][1])?([1-9]\d\d{7})$'`

PowerShell is not Perl, a leading `/` before the pattern is not expected - remove it.

The pattern itself could be described simply as `^(\+421)?([1-9]\d{8})$`

```
PS C:\> $phoneNumber = '+421233339135'
PS C:\> $phoneNumber -match '^(\+421)?([1-9]\d{8})$'
True
```

Comment: @PdeRover without knowing what $twelv and $thirt is, I'm not sure what to take away from your comment